# Item manages his click or call listener ? (recyclerView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listener

I have a `RecyclerView` which contains multiple item types (4 or 5 at least).
Some items can be clicked, sometimes they have two differents `clickListener` (for example two `imageView` in one item).
For now, the item manages the clicks himself like this :

```
item.imageView1.setOnClickListener(....){
     startActivity(Activity2);
}
item.imageView2.setOnClickListener(....){
     startActivity(Activity1);
}
```

But I have a problem : I need to put some variables in the activity which will be started, so what is the best way to do this :

1) My item need to know these variables and continues to manage his own click ?
2) My item has a `listener` which call startActivity with the variables (like the fragment or parent activity or an object dedicated to this) ?

If you need more precisions, ask me.

Thx.

Comment: I edited my post, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I know how to start an activity with parameter. My question is : "who has to know those parameter ? the item itself ? or item calls a listener (like his parents) ?

Answer (score 1):

Make an interface for passing those values.

```
public interface MyRecyclerCallback {
    void onItemClicked(Integer o); //insert whatever you want to pass further, possibly translated to form packable to intents 
}
```

- Then add it to your adapter from the activity with recycler like you would any listener. Either constructor or by separate method.
- Pass it further down to every children upon their creation.
- Call it when onClick gets detected with appropriate argument.

  The actual argument may be some abstract thing
  depending on your logic. It's more of a general idea. That's the way I do it with my recyclers.

In your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,new MyRecyclerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(Integer o) { //any argument you like, might be an abstract 
            Intent i = new Intent(this,ActivityTwo.class);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_VALUE,o);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.Child>{
    private final Context mContext;
    private final MyRecyclerCallback mCallback;
    private List<Integer> mChildren;

    public MyAdapter(Context ctx, MyRecyclerCallback myRecyclerCallback) {
        mContext = ctx;
        mCallback = myRecyclerCallback;
        mChildren = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void populateList(List<Integer> list ) { //this can be a network call or whatever you like
        mChildren.addAll(list);
    }

    @Override
    public Child onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new Child(v,mCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Child holder, int position) {
        holder.setValue1(mChildren.get(position)*3);
        holder.setValue2(mChildren.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mChildren.size();
    }

    public class Child extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView1;
        View mView2;
        private int mValue1;
        private int mValue2;


        public Child(View itemView, final MyRecyclerCallback mCallback) {
            super(itemView);
            mView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view1);
            mView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view2);

            mView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mCallback.onItemClicked(mValue1);
                }
            });

            mView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mCallback.onItemClicked(mValue2);
                }
            });
        }

        public void setValue1(int position) {
            mValue1 = position;
        }

        public void setValue2(int position) {
            mValue2=position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically yes. Usually it's my adapter who holds the data and children just pass it further to the one who wants callback. I prefer to send it back even if I want to start new activity with it because if at any time I would need a fragment there it would be much easier. Also if anything else is needed it can be done outside the view logic.

Comment: ok, but maybe it's not the right solution in this case because my item can be clicked in two places. Basically, one item has two clickable zones.

Comment: Give me a while I will edit my answer with some sample code.

Comment: ok, that's what I thought. In my case, it's complicated because my recycler has an adapter which doesn't what kind of items it has : some are clickable (two ways), others aren't. But I will try to adapt your solution (which was what I thought before asking the question.

Comment: Try to make your items have a common base class and operate on it. You could make a nice generic there. I have a project with huge class hierarchy that starts from one base class with a base generic adapter that follows the pattern above and it's totally reusable.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but the thing is items in the SAME list are completely different. Some have on click, others have two, others haven't. So, it's really to make a generic class or implements for this. And items' layouts are completely differents too.

Answer (score 0):

this a good alternative to handle onclick and onlongclick

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(mRecyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
        // do it
    }
});
```

http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single OnClickListener on your ViewHolder class and use it with an interface to determine the type of item which has been clicked.

For example, say you have a model class called Item :

```
public class Item {

   private int itemType;
   private String itemDescription;
   private String optionalExtra;

   public static final int ITEM_TYPE_1 = 1;
   public static final int ITEM_TYPE_2 = 2;

   public Item(int itemType, String itemDescription) {
      this.itemType = itemType;
      this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
   }

   public Item(int itemType, String itemDescription, String optionalExtra) {
      this.itemType = itemType;
      this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
      this.optionalExtra = optionalExtra;
   }

}
```

You have a custom interface defined to intercept click on items in recyclerview :

```
public interface CustomClickListener {
   void onClickOfItemType1( int position );
   void onClickOfItemType2( int position );
}
```

Inside your adapter for recyclerview, in the viewholder class :

```
//Similar implementation for other ViewHolders too.
public class ViewHolderType1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    View itemView;
    public ViewHolderType1(View view) {
       super(view);
       this.itemView = view;
       //initialize other views here

       //Set item click listener on your view
       itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      int itemPosition = getAdapterPosition();
      if( itemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION ) {
          customClickListener.onClickOfItemType1(itemPosition);
          //You can call onClickOfItemType2(itemPosition) in your other type of view holder class
      } 
    }

}
```

In your Activity or Fragment :

Pass the customClickListener as a parameter to your adapeter :

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(List<Item> itemList, new CustomClickListener {
   @Override
   void onClickOfItemType1(int position) {
      Item item = itemList.get(position);
      //This item is of type 1 
      //You can implement serializable / parcelable in your item class and use it to directly pass across item to your activity
      Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, CustomActivity1.class);
      intent.putExtra("item", item);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
   @Override
   void onClickOfItemType2(int position) {
      Item item = itemList.get(position);
      //This item is of type 2 
      //You can implement serializable / parcelable in your item class and use it to directly pass across item to your activity
      Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, CustomActivity2.class);
      intent.putExtra("item", item);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

In case you are trying to trigger different activities on click of different views; inside your viewclicklistener implementation check the view id and trigger the corresponding activity.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      int itemPosition = getAdapterPosition();
      if( itemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION ) {
          switch(v.getId()) {
             case R.id.imageView :
             customClickListener.onClickOfItemType1(itemPosition);
             break;
             case R.id.textView :
             customClickListener.onClickOfItemType2(itemPosition);
             break;
          }

       } 
    }
```

This is a guide for usage of RecyclerView :

https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview